# How to run iPhone simulator without showing the time?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Recently I use the iPhone simulator alot to make screenshots.

Sometimes it shows the time on the top and sometimes not.
I always just start the App in the simulator and sometimes the time shows, some other time the time does not show. I do not have any idea why this is.

So far I never really bothered but now I need a way to set this so the time does not show while the word "Carrier" and the battery icon in the top bar show.

**Is there any way to explicitly control this? 
Esp to run the App in simulator without showing the time?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Info.plist add the following key

[image: Info.plist]

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want the status bar to disappear - I just need to know how to start the App in simulator with/without time displayed...

Comment: @user387184 Photoshop it out.